# Rookie Obj-C problem - UITableViewCell selected displays no data in UIView sub view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, initialization, cells

I have  UITableViewCell which, when clicked displays a UIView loaded from a .xib file.  When I click the cell the view is successfully displayed however the data I want to display in the view elements won't display.

Code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Navigation logic
 NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");

 //Initialize a UIView that contains all the elements required to display the data
 EventDescriptionView *dView = [[EventDescriptionView alloc] init];
 //Set the data in the elements to the data contained in the xml
 //Set up the cell
 int storyIndex = indexPath.row;
 [[dView name] setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];
 [[dView date] setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"]];
 NSLog(@"Index: %d", storyIndex);
 [[dView image] setImage:[images objectAtIndex:storyIndex]];
 //Display the UIView
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft  forView:self.view cache:YES];

 [self.view addSubview:dView.view];

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

I can see the lines:

```
[[dView name] setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];
 [[dView date] setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"]];
 NSLog(@"Index: %d", storyIndex);
 [[dView image] setImage:[images objectAtIndex:storyIndex]];
```

Aren't recognising the dView elements and therefore successfully setting the data, but I don't understand how to get round this?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Side note Jack - some Obj-C purists will get mad at me for saying this, but as a rookie - adopt the easy notation, forget the old non-dot notation.  dView.name.text = foo is a LOT easier to read than [[dView name] setText:foo].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with this line.

```
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
```

This seems alien to a `UITableView` object as they map to `rows` and `sections`. Since I am expecting `stories` to map to the current row, I think your `storyIndex` should be –

```
int storyIndex = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean.  However I changed it and still got the same results..

Comment: Try logging the values to ensure that they are proper.

Comment: Are you using a NIB file for `EventDescriptionView`?

Comment: XIB and NIB are basically the same. Your problem is `EventDescriptionView *dView = [[EventDescriptionView alloc] init];`. It should be `EventDescriptionView *dView = [[EventDescriptionView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` if your xib name is `EventDescriptionView.xib` or set the nib name appropriately.

Comment: OK I've changed that as well, yet there is still a problem.  It think its the lines :

[[dView name] setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];
 [[dView date] setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"]];
 NSLog(@"Index: %d", storyIndex);
 [[dView image] setImage:[images objectAtIndex:storyIndex]];   That are causing the problem.

Comment: Jack - try NSLogging those values before you set them.  Are they correct?

Comment: Thanks madDad, I will try to make a habit of it in future. - Yes the values are correct before they are set.

Comment: Can you check if `dView.name` is not `nil`?

Comment: dView.name in the NSLog is:  NAME: <UILabel: 0x70409a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'photo Booth images
    '; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x702cad0>>     However the label does not display "photo Booth Images", it just says "Name" which is the default text.

Comment: Ok do not remove this NSLog statement and add a similar NSLog statement to `EventDescriptionView`'s `viewDidLoad` and paste both outputs here.

Comment: viewDidLoad NAME: <UILabel: 0x5c3e5f0; frame = (148 20; 147 36); text = 'Name'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x5c3cfa0>>                             didSelectRowAtIndexPath NAME: <UILabel: 0x5c340f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'photo Booth images
    '; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x5c3de10>>

Comment: The labels are two different instances. Can you check `dView` here and `self` there similarly to see if they are same or different instances?

Comment: I understand what you mean about the 2 different instances, but can you elaborate on the check?

Comment: I mean `UILabel: 0x5c3e5f0` & `UILabel: 0x5c340f0` told me that they were different labels.

Comment: Aye, I understand that. I just don't understand how to prevent that and therefore have the text set correctly?

Comment: If they are two different objects, its likely that you are creating a second instance somewhere and loading it instead. It doesn't seem that it is the case from the code I have seen but I have seen only a little. If they are different, you will need to identify where the second initialization is taking place.

Comment: Cheers for putting up with me deepak, certainly sounds like the cause of the problem. Will report back once I've solved it.  Thanks for your help.